# Pyomo DAE optimization - IPOPT not reproducible results

Tags: python, pyomo, ipopt

I recently started experiencing some issues when using Pyomo for optimizing a DAE problem with parameter estimation.

I use Python 2.7.12 with Anaconda2 4.1.1 in Windows 10 and as solver Ipopt 3.11.1

Every time that I run my script I am getting different estimates and the number of iterations at when Ipopt finishes the optimization also differs between each and other run. The issue started when I installed ArcGis and I guess that it made some changes in my previously installed version of Python.

I got rid of ArcGis completely, and have reinstalled Python, Anaconda and Ipopt three times cleaning up the registry with Ccleaner. However, the problem still persists.

What can be done?

Comment: Can you check if the NL file that is being sent to Ipopt changes from run to run on an identical model (keepfiles=True or --keepfiles with the `pyomo` command will print the NL file name and allow you to `diff` them, although I don't know how to `diff` files on Windows)? This would help us determine if it is a problem with Pyomo or if it's simply that Ipopt returns different answers (which I've seen happen).

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have compared the NL files for some runs with the fc command in cmd windows (something alike diff in linux), and there is no difference between them @GabeHackebeil

Comment: Well that's unfortunate. If you figure out any magic Ipopt options that fix this, I'd be curious hear about it.

Comment: Are you using any Pyomo Set components in your model? If so then try adding the 'ordered=True' keyword argument to their declaration and see if that makes a difference (This may be the same as checking the NL file as Gabe suggested). Are you using dat files to load data into your model? Does Ipopt return an 'optimal solution' status after each run?

Comment: @BethanyNicholson Yes, I do use a Pyomo Set component. I tried adding the keyword that you suggest but the results still differ between each other. I checked the NL files from these too, and there is no difference. Yes, I am using a dat file to load data into my model and finally Ipopt returns most of the times an 'optimal solution' (sometimes it gives results with bad status errors). Interestingly, today I tried the same script in another PC, and it works fine, the results are exactly the same no matter how many times I run it.

Comment: I still guess that it is the result of had installed ArcGis (which uses python too) what messed up my PC